# lua return string c++

Tags: c++, lua

There is a function on Lua:

```
STRING getClassesList()
```

It returns string as it is to get on c++:

This does not work:

```
Const char * ClassesStr;
Lua_getglobal (L, "getClassesList");
Lua_pcall (L, 1, 1, 0);
ClassesStr = lua_tostring (L, 1);
```

stack: 'readQuikAgent' 'attempt to call a table value'

The function is designed to obtain a list of class codes sent from the server during the communication session. The class codes in the list are separated by a comma ",". At the end of the received line, the symbol "," is always appended.

Call format:

STRING getClassesList ()

Example:

List = getClassesList ()

As a result of the above line of code, the list variable contains a string of the form:

OPTEXP, USDRUB, PSOPT, PSFUT, SPBFUT

Comment: What is `readQuikAgent`?

Comment: This is my program.

Comment: Then you didn't show enough code.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `STRING getClassesList()` is not a valid Lua function signature.

Comment: add some of the lua code to the example please - where getClassesList() is implemented.

Comment: lua: message(getClassesList()) output: OPTEXP, USDRUB, PSOPT, PSFUT, SPBFUT

Comment: Your specific `lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0)` call expects the function *and one argument* on the Lua stack. You only push the function.

Comment: @HenriMenke it's from qlua, some custom lua+qt framework :)

Answer (score 2):

'attempt to call table value' means that the item at the top of the `lua` stack is a `table` not a `function`.

So the result of the getglobal was a table, and that can not be called.

Answer (score 1):

It works (thank you siffiejoe):

```
lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0);
ClassesStr = lua_tostring(L, -1);
```